# Magento 2 - Call different module block function in my custom phtml

Tags: magento2, blocks, phtml

I have custom module in which there is custom block and it's associated phtml which call my custom block functions using `$block` object.

I want to call other module block function in my custom module phtml

So I need to figure out the best way of doing it? I already have the idea how to call other block function in phtml through `Objectmanager` but it is not the best practice

Any help, knowledge and experience sharing would be appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You Can Call Another Module Block Like This :-**

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('\Vendor\Module\Block\FileName')->yourFunction();
```

Comment: Let me try this, come back to you :)

Comment: It worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome.. Happy Coding :)